# How to create Apple Watch app in Xcode or configure Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

How to create iWatch app with Xcode? or how to configure iWatch in existing project?

Comment: What is the point of asking a question you already know the answer to and the answer is basically re-stating information from Apple's guide and providing a link to the guide. An Internet search of "Apple Watch development" returns a link to the same guide.

Comment: just user can find information easily so i posted here people can user more stackoverflow.com then apple doc ....

Comment: You can refer the same from apple docs.

Answer (score 24):

You must have an existing iOS app to create a WatchKit app. The WatchKit app is implemented as a separate target of your Xcode project and is built and packaged inside your iOS app’s bundle.

**To add a WatchKit app target to your existing iOS app project**

1) In Xcode, open the project for your iOS app.

2) Select File > New > Target, and navigate to the Apple Watch section.

3) Select WatchKit App, then click Next.

4)If you plan to implement a glance or custom notification interface, select the appropriate checkboxes.
For notification interfaces, it is recommended that you select the Include Notification Scene checkbox, even if you do not plan on implementing that interface right away. Selecting that checkbox adds an additional file to your project for debugging your notification interfaces. If you do not select that option, later you must create the file manually.

5) Click Finish.

Xcode configures the targets for your WatchKit app and WatchKit extension and adds the needed files to your iOS project. The bundle IDs for both new targets are configured automatically, based on the bundle ID of your iOS app. The base IDs for all three bundles must match; if you change your iOS app’s bundle ID, you must update the other bundle IDs accordingly.

[see apples doc: HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1)

Comment: This should be the selected answer, IMO

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question

1. List item create a new project select single view app
2. fill project detail finish.
3. now select file > target > in IOS section showing a apple watch select this
4. press next then press finish
5. now xcode ask "Activate “yourProjectName WatchKit App” scheme?" select active

now in your target showing a WatchKit Extension

for more info goto [apple link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

An Apple Watch app is just an extension of the main app running on a paired iPhone.You must have an existing iOS app to create a WatchKit app. The WatchKit app is implemented as a separate target of your Xcode project and is built and packaged inside your iOS app’s bundle.

This guide gives complete/detailed information about apple watch development including how to create Apple Watch app with Xcode.

[Apple Watch documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/10tdnc5owifbvsl/AppleWatch-Documentation.pdf?dl=0)